# skimage.io.imshow does not display image

Tags: python, image, path

I am facing a problem of not able to display image with the following command:

```
from skimage import io
io.imshow('abc.png')
```

It shows following error:

```
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.pyc in     new_figure_manager(num, *args, **kwargs)
 78     FigureClass = kwargs.pop('FigureClass', Figure)
 79     figure = FigureClass(*args, **kwargs)
---> 80     window = Tk.Tk()
 81     canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, master=window)
 82     figManager = FigureManagerTkAgg(canvas, num, window)

/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.pyc in __init__(self, screenName, baseName, className, useTk, sync, use)
 1686                 baseName = baseName + ext
 1687         interactive = 0
 -> 1688         self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
 1689         if useTk:
 1690             self._loadtk()
 TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

I am running this in remote server. In the server, I found the DISPLAY variable is not set. 
How do I set the display variable to display the image.

Comment: What is your **HOST**? And which program do you use to connect to the server?.

Comment: I am connecting to a linux server using ssh -X hostname.

Comment: no its from linux(ubuntu) machine.

Comment: check out http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-from-ubuntu-machine

Comment: I tried it. Now it does not show the error but image is not still displayed.

Comment: Running in an iPython Notebook still showed no image. it worked only with `matplotlib`. `%matplotlib inline`  `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`   `plt.imshow(im)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-from-ubuntu-machine) link to configure my client computer. I was using ipython. For ipython, while starting with it, I run command as:

```
 ipython --pylab %sets  up graphics  for plotting
```

This works for me now.